# how to Sort Gridview At A Pageload itself?

Tags: sorting, gridview, pageload

I have this code of mine on pageload, please have a look:

```
var d = from p in db.Questions
                where p.CatId == Convert.ToInt32(s)
                select p;
        DataTable datatable =d as DataTable;
        DataView dataview = new DataView(datatable);
        dataview.Sort ="id DESC" ;

        GridView1.DataSource =dataview;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

I have a column named "id" in the table "Questions" on which I want to sort the gridview on pageload itself.
The following Error shows up during compilation:

## DataTable must be set prior to using DataView.

Please Help.

Comment: So, why do you not sort by id when you query the data?  Or are you wanting to add the sort direction for sort direction arrow???

Answer (score 0):

well, I already Figured out the answer. Here is the code which I inserted

```
    var d = from p in db.Questions
    orderby p.Dtime descending
    where p.CatId == Convert.ToInt32(s)
    select p;
    DataTable datatable =d as DataTable;
    DataView dataview = new DataView(datatable);
    dataview.Sort ="id DESC" ;
    GridView1.DataSource =dataview;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```